# Does the Warburg effect have any relevance to the effective treatment of cancer with diet?

Tags: cancer

There's a book by Thomas Seyfried, a professor of biology, that claims cancer is a metabolic disease and that it can be treated with diet, specifically a ketogenic diet as aberrant mitchondria are said to be underlie cancer, and you can starve them by using ketone bodies instead of glucose to fuel the body without fueling the cancer.

He presents some poor data from the treatment of glioblastomas and from this makes this claim

> The low-carb, high-fat ketogenic diet can replace chemotherapy and radiation for even the deadliest of cancers, said Dr. Thomas Seyfried, a leading cancer researcher and professor at Boston College.

Is there any high quality evidence at all for the role of ketogenic diets in the management of a malignancy that is exhibiting the Warburg effect?